# How to disable the back button in the browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the back button for a website.

Whenever the person clicks on the browser back button it should not be able to go on the page the user visited before.

Comment: (a) Such a horrible idea from a usability perspective. (b) See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript

Comment: You simply cannot and should not do this. However, you might find the [`unload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload) useful.

Comment: there is a time, place, and need for everything. but the haters have to hate. I could list a bunch of reasons in today's ajax powered web apps where this would be necessary.

Comment: try this , a different approach
http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/archive/2010/05/18/back-button-issue-after-logout-in-asp.net.aspx

Comment: also refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28458499/2089963

Comment: window.history.forward(1);

Comment: Voting to reopen as answers here provide updated info regarding this topic (new answers on this other page would be buried at the bottom). This Q&A supersedes the old one.

Answer (score -39, accepted):

You can't, and you shouldn't.

Every other approach / alternative will only cause really bad user engagement.

That's my opinion.

Comment: Let's say you are on an online exam, then it got a little sense.

Comment: I think an alert and confirm would work better

Comment: See Shailendra Sharma's answer for why I voted -1 on this accepted answer.

Comment: The most practical example why you **should** be able to do this, is that when clicking the Back button in Firefox, and you have an iframe open that made a history change, the iframe will go back, not the entire page. That's just bull.

Comment: In some cases it is needed. If you were displaying a web view, and had control over browser history, you might wanna disable back button at certain point. Consider a situation in which you are ordering something in web view, if you are not disabling back you might end up in double ordering same thing unnecessarily.

Comment: You are right this is something only bad websites do there is an onbeforeunload event for this.

Comment: If an online exam blocks the back button that way, then that online exam is completley, and utterly worthless. This limitation can be worked around in so many ways it's not even funny (including "without even noticing" ways)

Comment: @Sanchitos Or a payment ...

Comment: There is a very valid use case for this: When you are designing a web app with partial views and you want to ensure that the app performs expected behavior when the back button is pressed. In that case the back button doesn't actually do what the user might expect unless you provide code for it. "Disabling" it isn't the same, but you are applying the same concept (modifying the behavior of the back button). You can't stop users from clicking back, so you might as well make the app do what they expect.

Comment: I need to disable it for my customer service reps to create a BETTER experience. If you don't know all the facts, then don't judge the method.

Comment: Please note that your Answer was discussed at meta in [Opinion only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401844/opinion-only-answers)

Answer (score 264):

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.title);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.title);
});
```

This script will overwrite attempts to navigate back and forth with the state of the current page.

---

Update:

Some users have reported better success with using `document.URL` instead of `document.title`:

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. It works on Chrome, IE11 and the iPad's Safari. Someone down-voted it regardless of its usefulness.

Comment: Would this also affect the browser's back button?

Comment: I ended up doing this:

 onpopstate = function (event) {            
            window.location.hash = '';
            return(null);
 };

It works for me as I expect, but this answer helped me understand what I should do.

Comment: It worked just as explained but I needed to specify pagename as ' ' otherwise I got the page name in the URL. I placed this code in a layout page, common to all others and maybe that is the reason.

Comment: The reason this is getting downvotes is because disabling standard browser functionality is about the *worst UX practice that exists*. However, the answer itself is the correct answer to the question, meaning this answer should technically be upvoted.

Comment: It works on Firefox too

Comment: Downvoting : as it changes the URL and due to which site crashes on refresh.

Comment: Works like a charm     window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {

        var hash = computePageHash();
        if (hash != $('#PAGE_STATE').val()) {
            alert('You have unsaved changes!');
            history.pushState(null, null,'#');
        }
        else
        {
            history.back();
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, '#');
        savePageHash();
    });

Comment: @Mckenzie the URL is changed because of history.pushState(null, null, document.title); statement. It puts title of the page in the URL and this causes the crash on refresh. You can replace **document.title** with your page URL. This will solves your issue. Before downvoting please try to understand the code. It's one of the best solutions I found so far.

Comment: @ArjunAjith Please could you show us how to replace document.title for the site url ??

Comment: @jsanchezs  The code will change only the last part of the URL. Here it is changed with document.title parameter which provides title of the page. Just change it with the orginal part. Like change it to 'login' if your orginal URL is www.myadress.com/login

Comment: @jsanchezs Please go through the following link.. This is my modification on the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511893/prevent-back-button-after-logout/37786044#37786044

Comment: @ArjunAjith thanks for your answer, but itś not that easy if my script it's in a base.js from where all templates take reference...i mean, there should be a way to capture the actual url name isn't it ?

Comment: I used above code and found that there is big problem with the code. But I have also fixed that code by a little change. New code is:
    
    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    });

Comment: As @ArjunAjith suggest, I replaced `document.title` with `document.url` and it is working. +1 for this answer.

Comment: <script>
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
</script>

Comment: This works great, unlike geevee thinks, this is very useful. I am using it on a single page web app so user do not accidentally leave the app when hitting  the backspace button and are not on a text input.

Comment: If you need help setting the document URL go here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL

Comment: To be noted that this doesn't disable long-pressing of the back button. That behaves normally and lets you go back in history.

Comment: any clue on how implement this on angular2?

Comment: Great, it work for me. I spent my lot of time to find solution, but this is really work for me.
Thanks

Comment: refresh button is not work correctly.

Comment: Not working for me. I put the code in the script tag of the head tag. Any idea why it wouldn't work?

Comment: Hi, the above solution is not working in ie browser.

Comment: @ShailendraSharma Sharma in ie it is not working. when I refresh the page it is working

Comment: it should be
`history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event)
{
  history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
});`
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34337617/2073920

Answer (score 24):

One cannot disable the browser back button functionality. The only thing that can be done is prevent them.

The below JavaScript code needs to be placed in the head section of the page where you don’t want the user to revisit using the back button:

```
<script>
    function preventBack() {
        window.history.forward();
    }

    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload = function() {
        null
    };
</script>
```

Suppose there are two pages `Page1.php` and `Page2.php` and `Page1.php` redirects to `Page2.php`.

Hence to prevent user from visiting `Page1.php` using the *back button* you will need to place the above script in the head section of `Page1.php`.

For more information: **[Reference](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Browser-Back-Button-Functionality-using-JavaScript.aspx)**

Comment: Reference code not working in Chrome.

Comment: Also I couldn't work it in Firefox

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and IE. Thanks!

Answer (score -11):

Our approach is simple, but it ***works***! :)

When a user clicks our LogOut button, we simply open the login page (or any page) and close the page we are on...simulating opening in new browser window without any history to go back to.

```
<input id="btnLogout" onclick="logOut()" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" value="Logout" type="button"/>
<script>
    function logOut() {
        window.close = function () { 
            window.open('Default.aspx', '_blank'); 
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The browser warns the user that the site is trying to close their page, and they have the option to click cancel...so here we only redirect them if they truly are logging out and leaving the page.

Comment: use history.pushState() works in all modern browsers which support the HTML5 History API

Comment: Opening a new window does not have any history for that tab or window and hence this works. but if you want to stay in same window, this is not even close to answering that question.

Comment: @dhruvpatel In GNOME’s Epiphany browser, opening new views (tabs/windows) _does_ inherit the history of the parent view.