# Web Page Redirect and Block Return

Tags: redirect, html

I'm using a simple (Meta) timed redirect on a web page. The viewer may wait the allotted time or click on a link to leave the page. I would like to block the viewer's ability to return to the original page after leaving it.

I've been cautioned about using Meta scripts due to the possibility of search engine rejection- true or not, I haven't a clue.

If possible, I would like to avoid Java or the use of cookies. Nonetheless, if Java is the best or only solution, I am open to it.

Your thoughts and guidance are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post any code/methods that you have tried already?

Comment: Really, the few things I've tried were very much amateurish and pedestrian. Nothing for you to hang your hat on so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<script>
  function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
  setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
  window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```

You can place that code on the page that you don't want the user accessing using the back button in the head section. But, it is not recommended since it might annoy your users.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926641/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-using-javascript) post explains things in a bit more detail from multiple users.

Comment: Thanks. The script worked well for blocking a return via the browser's back button. However, the page is retained in the browser history and can also be accessed by direct entry of the address in the address bar.

Comment: The blocked "back button" shouldn't pose a problem. It's not global and the average viewer shouldn't be troubled by the inability to return to the page in question- it's simply a "thank you". Basically, I'm just trying to make the operation a bit more professional, polished, if you will. Then, again, I may be "putting lipstick on a pig". Perhaps, I'm going for a bit too much? Thanks again, and thanks to wolfer-east as well.

Comment: @sedwick Was my post helpful?

Comment: @sedwick Then could I get a thumbs up please :)?

Comment: Hello Mr. Concolato. Unfortunately my reputation hasn't reached the level required to submit a vote. However, I did invoke the check mark ("tick" for all the Anglophiles) indicating the answer was accepted.