# Prevent user to go back after payment timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

To prevent user to go back, I used the below code :

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
history.pushState(null, null, 'pagename');
});
</script>
```

I found it from the below link:

[How to disable back button in browser using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926641/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-using-javascript)

However, this works fine in Chrome but not working in firefox and IE. In inspect element i can see the script in Chrome but its not there in firefox and IE.