# Brower back button issue in wordpress after logout

Tags: php, wordpress, browser, browser-cache

I am using the below redirect code in the `functions.php` file.

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
   $adfsurllogouturl = 'some url';
   wp_redirect( $adfsurllogouturl );exit();
}
```

It's working fine. The issue is that once logged out, it redirects to `SOMEURL` when I click on the back button of the browser from the redirected page, it shows previous page details.
But I want that it should go on the login page.

I used the below code to fix it but it's not working.

```
function check_if_user_is_loggedin_action()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
    {
        header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
        header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
        header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
    }
}
add_action('init', 'check_if_user_is_loggedin_action');
```

Please suggest to me. Is it the correct way?

Comment: Please, see an update to my first answer with a correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem as follows.

I added a cookie in the `functions.php` file just after logging in.

```
function login_function() {
    setcookie('wp_user_logged_in', 1, time() + 31556926, '/');
    $_COOKIE['wp_user_logged_in'] = 1;
}
add_action('wp_login', 'login_function');
```

I deleted and set the cookie value to NULL in the `functions.php` file just after logout.

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
  unset($_COOKIE['wp_user_logged_in']);
  setcookie('wp_user_logged_in', null, -1, '/');
  wp_safe_redirect( '/login-page' );
  exit();
}
```

Added following javascript in `footer.php` file to check the user is logout and reload the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){         
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('wp_user_logged_in') !== -1) {
            //do something when user logged in
        } else {
            //do something when user logged out
            window.location.reload();//reload page
        }
    },2000);
</script>
```

Comment: @Ryan and Mora, I resolved it thanks

Comment: I have tried this but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

To redirect users after successfull logout to the needed page, you can add the following code:

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
  wp_safe_redirect( '/login-page' );
  exit();
}
```

With the following button code:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Instead of `/login-page` please, use the needed URL.

Upd.

According to the solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40766644/17572092

You can use below code to check for session variable:

```
<?php 
      if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) : 
      header("Location: login.php");  
?>
```

When user logout destroy the session:

```
<?php
      unset($_SESSION['login']);  
      session_destroy();  
?>
```

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
<pre><code>
add_action(‘wp_logout’,’auto_redirect_after_logout’);

function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
     wp_redirect( home_url() );
     exit();
}
add_action( ‘check_admin_referer’, function($action, $result) {
    if ( ‘log-out’ == $action && is_user_logged_in() && !empty($_GET[‘action’]) 
          && ‘logout’ == $_GET[‘action’] ) {
         wp_logout();
         wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Try out this code !!

Comment: Answer was not readable so i edited.

Comment: This code not working for me