# Browser back button and javascript

Tags: javascript, button, browser, back, onbeforeunload

It's possible to show some message on the page when you set mouse cursor on the browser back button? I don't want to use `window.onbeforeunload`, because it's irritating. I use ajax and I want to inform users that if they want to go back to the previous page on my web portal they should use a different button.

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to handle the mouse moving on the browser buttons, these are not part of the DOM that your scripts can handle.

There is an [answer available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25665232), which proposes a way of preventing users going back through the browser's back button.