# Custom Div when press browser back button

Tags: javascript, browser

[image]

Pressing Back button in Google Plus will show this nice Div, instead of the ugly alert box, how is this achievable? Notice the URL has not change when press 'Back'.

Thanks.

Edit:
I should be more specific in my question. I am not interested at how sexy the pop-up modal, but I am looking for method or API to hijack the back button behavior.

Comment: Hi-jack the back button like so: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926641/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-using-javascript

... and then build a modal functionality and call the modal to open.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses their own material design for all their products, its nothing but a simple dialog box with material design css.

some third party websites offer this design for free, in that http://getmdl.io has all type of components for any design

[Check the Dialog here](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#dialog-section) and [here](http://codepen.io/Garbee/full/EPoaMj/)

```
<!-- http://codepen.io/... -->
```