# Trying to disable the browser's back button

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I've written two HTML files:

1. Login.html
   `<a href = "Home.html">Next Page</a>`
2. Home.html`

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <a href = >Login.html>>Prev Page</a>
   </body>
<script type = "text/javascript" >

 history.pushState("anything", "", "#1");
     window.onhashchange = function (event) {
         window.location.hash = "a";
     };
</script>
</html>
```

`
I'm trying to disable browser's back button. If i execute this code on chrome it doesn't disable the back button but if i run `history.state` command in console of Home.html page and then i click the back button, then it remains on same page(works as expected). Why so?

Comment: See [how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript) and [How to disable back button in browser using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926641/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-using-javascript).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FOA, Thanks everyone for your answers.

Finally below code gave me the solution:

```js
history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
history.back();
window.onpopstate = () => history.forward();
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the first 2 lines are required? Just adding `window.onpopstate = () => history.forward();` is working fine for me

Comment: where do I add this line of code? I am using ASP.Net MVC 4.8

Comment: @Saksham Chaudhary infosec security issues will come with : window.location.href

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable the browser's back button. If you could, that would be a security hazard and the browser vendors would most likely seek to fix it.

Comment: according to the acceped answer this is deprecated, right?

Comment: no. the first answer is manipulating history, not disabling the back button

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 History API gives developers the ability to modify a website's URL without a full page refresh. This is particularly useful for loading portions of a page with JavaScript, such that the content is significantly different and warrants a new URL.

You can check this link it may helpful

https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/