# Disable browser back button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that blocks back button in the browser, however, it doesn't work,

```
function test (e) {
        if (performance.navigation.type == 2)  {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Is there a solution that will work on major browsers, can anybody try to help me with this?

Comment: @Charlie, no,  it doesn't work in the Chrome

Comment: Very annoying user experience doing this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983529/trying-to-disable-the-browsers-back-button Duplicate