# JS Disable browser back button as soon as your page is ready

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser, javascript-objects

I am trying to disable the browser back button via JS code and have already seen lot of answers like
[How can I stop the browser back button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-back-button-using-javascript)
and
[Trying to disable the browser's back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983529/trying-to-disable-the-browsers-back-button)

But my problem is unique, The issue is that once my page is loaded and I don't click inside the document (Anywhere on the page) my browser back button still function the way it use to.

But If I click inside the document/page, all the above scripts and code works properly.

So the I want to ask that if there is any way I can make the document(page) active somehow so that if the user click directly on back button without clicking inside the page, They should not go back.